# Navigation won't show in DIV

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, html-lists

This is an overused navigation I'm sure. I'm using it to edit what I want out of it to be honest, but I'm missing the main goal; getting it in my page. I've tried everything for hours now, and can't get it to show up correctly in a div I have on my page. Hopefully someone will see what I'm missing.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGjhD/)

Please go to my test page to see what it should be like here: http://imengine.gofreeserve.com/fileshare/fileshare2/test/testlogin.html

And what it is actually doing here (dont know how to put images in jsfiddle):
since i can only post 2 links, its the link above except fileshare/fileshare2/index2.php

Comment: Yea works fine for me, where are you trying to put it exactly? Edit: I see the problem now looking at the HTML

Comment: If I put it by itself on a page it's fine, but in a div with placements i have it breaks it all up. Any ideas?

Comment: You're only talking about of 'getting it done' without specifying what **is** *well done.* What is a 'right position' for you? What means *show up correctly in a div* ?

Comment: It's explained in the jsFiddle and shown on my link to my test page, but there is an absolute positioned div on my page where this menu is supposed to be placed in. I'm not sure why, but placing it in this div breaks it up and doesnt show up properly or work correctly. If I put the menu on a page by itself with nothing else, it works perfectly fine. I need it to show up in this div for this position somehow though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give an exact answer, but something with the navigation menu, its javascript, and the janko menu and it's javascript, at the least (maybe something with css on them too?) was colliding together and breaking it. I redid the navigation menu for the pages, and this works just fine now. I have no idea, but it seemed it may have been the javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the fileshare2/index2.php page, I can see your problem. The the drop down menu for the Janko at Warp Speed menu bar area isn't sized correctly. This stems from a menu.css min-width property. To correct the drop down menus going outside the indicated boxes, change menu.css's ul attribute:

```
ul {
cursor: pointer;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
min-width: 200px; /* change this to 150px instead */
padding: 0;
}
```

The excess padding around the "Login" and "Help" menus can be removed by applying a style of `padding: 0;` to `#menu li`. That should make the menu you're using look like you want it to, not including the unstyled "Home," "Projects" and "Admin" menus. Hope it helps and is what you're looking for.

Comment: the menu.css is for the navigation bar with "home","projects" ect, and I didn't notice the ul was not named, so I switched it into navigation (the "home" navigation). I did however change the min width. 
I also added the padding:0;, but the janko menu is still doing the same thing.

Comment: And I ended up adding it back to fix my other menu. :)

Comment: The test page at fileshare/fileshare2/index2.php seems to work fine now for me anyway. Were you able to fix everything? The Janko menu seems to act like it should, too.

Comment: Yeah something was up. I think it was in the javascript, but not really sure. Regardless redid the navigation and they both work. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

I looked this over in Firebug continously to try and see the problem.

Everything was correctly positioning itself except for the most outer div which had CSS of:

```
#loginbar {
    height: auto;
    left: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    visibility: visible;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

The left and top causes the menu to display in a weird position, i.e. not at the top of the page which is probably what your trying to do here.

Zeroing these values will stop the menu floating in a specific position.

You can also take out the position absolute as well to stop it floating. But since the elements on fileshare/fileshare2/index2.php are floating absolute I recommend you change your CSS dramatically if you wish to do this.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I actually needed the div positioned where it was. I wouldn't know how else to position it there though, if you have any suggestions. Also, I took a whack at taking out the position, right, and top values and it still didn't show up right (looked the same as before).

Comment: @GrantKesslerJr I am very confused and I think everyone else is too. I looked at your demo page and it all seemed to fit with the CSS etc. Maybe this is a browser thing? What browser are you using? Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: @GrantKesslerJr Cos yea on the latest FF removing, as you say in the fiddle, the absolute div does nothing but stop it floating 400px off center for me.

Comment: What it's actually doing (breaking up the menu): http://imengine.gofreeserve.com/fileshare/fileshare2/test/Untitled.png
What it should be doing (except in the position on the first link, not just up on the top left of the page): http://imengine.gofreeserve.com/fileshare/fileshare2/test/Untitled33.png

Comment: @GrantKesslerJr Can you host those on imgur and edit your question with them. You will see in the editor the ability to enter pictures, use that cos your provider is blocking me from seeing them

Comment: http://imgur.com/6ig9E , http://imgur.com/hMXQI sorry about that. First image is how it should be, 2nd is what its doing on ie9. Oddly, besides the search bar, on my phone it showed up fine, and it worked, on ie9 the drop downs don't work or anything.